# Intel MiniPCIe Wireless Adapter - Main/Aux connector, Black/Grey cable

Tags: wireless-networking, antenna

I was wondering if there is a different between "Main" and "Aux" connector on the MiniPCIe Wireless Adapter? Also, the black and grey antenna cable has different length. Are there any industry standard for the length and color of the antenna cable? Is it correct if we connect black cable to Main connector and grey cable to Aux connector

Example:
Intel® Wireless WiFi Link 4965AGN
http://www.intel.com/products/wireless/wireless_n/overview.htm

Comment: Just some updates: According to an engineer in related field, wireless card first gets the signals from Antenna connected to MAIN connector. If the signal is not good, it will get the signal from Antenna connected at AUX connector. Hence suggests putting shorter cable to MAIN connector because shorter cable will have less signal loss. Please comment. Thanks!